# Python turtle draw a fatline with three parameters

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

> Write a function named `fatLine()`. The function `fatLine()` takes
>   three parameters:
>
> 1. a turtle, `t`
> 2. an integer, `segments`, that is the number of segments in the line that is drawn
> 3. an integer, `increment`, that is how much wider each successive segment of the line is
>
> The function `fatLine()` should use the turtle t to draw a line
>   composed of connected segments.  Each segment should be of length 50.
>   The width of the first line segment should be (the parameter) 
>   `increment`, and each successive segment should be wider than the
>   preceding segment by `incremen`t.  For example, if `segments = 5` and
>   `increment = 10`, the following is correct output

I tried coding this with three parameters and i am not sure how else i would make it run. Any help would be great  Thanks.
I am trying to code this in idle but i have no luck. Please help with any idea on how to execute.

Comment: This is obviously homework. Can you show us the code you've tried so far, and tell us how you've tried to run it in IDLE?

Comment: If you are saying that you tried some code, it is best to paste it, we will help you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been five years, it's time this question, despite not showing coding effort, had an answer:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def fatLine(t, segments, increment):
    width = increment

    for _ in range(segments):
        t.width(width)
        t.forward(50)
        width += increment

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

turtle.penup()
turtle.backward(200)
turtle.pendown()

fatLine(turtle, 8, 10)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]